# Why does git (sometimes) clone a commit when merging?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I'm aware that there are some scenarios that lead to Git commits being duplicated, for example a `git cherry-pick`. If a commit is cherry-picked and "merged" into another branch, it appears twice in the commit graph, with two commit hashes.

Is it possible that Git duplicates a commit during a `git merge` operation?

The reason I'm asking is the following commit graph (generated in TortoiseGit):

[image]

The commits are listed in 'date-order' here (author date).

After I committed `efb916..` in the green branch (which was my `master` branch then), I merged the green branch into the red branch (which is a local side branch). This appears as a regular merge in the graph. So far so good.

After that, I clicked the Sync button in Github for Windows to sync my local `master` to the remote `origin/master`. This pulled the commit `09067c..` from the remote branch and then merged or rebased the local `master`, so commit `09067c..` was followed by commit `efb916..`. However, instead of **really merging** `efb916..` onto `09067c..`, Git duplicated commit `efb916..` and gave the duplicate the new hash `48e314..`.

In the end, my `master` pointed at `48e314..` (the black branch in the graph) and my local side branch pointed at `68b78a..` (the red branch). The contents, date, author and message of the commits `efb916..` and `48e314..` are exactly the same.

This has happened several times, sometimes with just one commit being duplicated, sometimes with several commits.

**Why did git duplicate the commit `efb916..`? How can I prevent it?**

**EDIT:** As an additional note: I find it strange that my `master` originally pointed at `efb916..`, but after the Github Sync `efb916..` was no longer in the commit history of `master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and then merged or rebased the local

It rebased. When you rebase you create duplicate shas.  When you merge you create a single merge commit.

You can trigger a rebase via 'pull' a few different ways.  You'd have to look at your configuration to see which ones are applicable for your situation.

Manually pass --rebase to pull

```
git pull --rebase
```

Configure pull to perform a rebase by default instead of a merge (this setting could be in your global, repo, or system config file)

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Then additionally there could be a per-branch setting in the repo config like

```
branch.<branch>.rebase true
```

Answer (score 4):

So, I'm going to break this down into a simple view first.  But it's not entirely accurate, but it's easier to get a grasp.  Then I'll give you resources for further reading afterward.

**The Simple View**

The problem is that you're confused about what a commit really is.  The commit hash is not a hash of your patch, it's more of a hash of the system as a whole.  So when you merge, it's functionally applying all the patches in both (or more) branches that you're merging, coming up with a new complete code tree, and creating it in the object tree with a hash that is representational of the current state.

A rebase is similar: you're functionally moving all the patches in the tree and the result will be different.  They're different because the order the patches are applied matters and affects the hash.  You can actually do this as an easy test to show the difference:

Create a new repository with a single file:

```
# echo "a" >> file
# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/hardaker/tmp/h/test/.git/
# (master #): git add file
# (master #): git commit -m "new file"
[master (root-commit) 9617f27] new file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
```

Now, let's branch it:

```
# (master): git checkout -b new-branch
Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'
```

Add a new file in the branch:

```
# (new-branch): echo "file2" > file2
# (new-branch): git add file2 
P# (new-branch +): git commit -m "new file2" file2 
[new-branch 04f3fdf] new file2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file2
```

Check out the master again and make a change there:

```
# (new-branch): git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
# (master): echo "b" >> file 
# (master *): git commit -m "added b" -a
[master 3b3de88] added b
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now, lets display the log as a tree form and see what we have so far:

```
# (master):  git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
* 3b3de88 (HEAD, master) added b
| * 04f3fdf (new-branch) new file2
|/  
* 9617f27 new file
```

A nice tree view, with two branches.  Note the commit ID of the
new-branch, because it's about to change when we rebase new-branch
onto master:

```
# (master): git checkout new-branch 
Switched to branch 'new-branch'
# (new-branch): git rebase master
 file | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: new file2
```

And the branch head no longer has the same commit id because you've
changed how the system is constructed.

```
# (new-branch):  git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
* d9918d4 (HEAD, new-branch) new file2
* 3b3de88 (master) added b
* 9617f27 new file
```

Now, for good reading fun on what a commit really is, and what objects
in the tree really are, read [The Git
Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) web page.  You'll learn oh so much in just a few pages.

Comment: Thank you. You answer the question *Why does the same commit have different hash values?*. But I'd like to know why Git/Github for Windows sometimes generates a duplicate commit with the same contents (same diff) and sometimes not.

Comment: @cheeesus, the commits have different hash values because they're *not* the same commit :-). Commit hashes are generated based on many attributes of the commit including its content, its commit message, its timestamp, and *its parent(s)*. Even if you go through the effort to make sure that everything else is identical, including timestamps, if the parent commits are different the hash will be different.

Comment: Chris is right.  Read the web page at the very bottom of my answer and you'll see exactly what goes into a commit set.  It is *not* a duplicate, actually.  The patch may seem like a duplicate, but the change set stored by git is not a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 1):

**git merge** never duplicates commits, it only creates new ones (merge commits)

**git rebase** DOES duplicate commits

**git cherry-pick** DOES duplicate commits

If you don't use git rebase and git cherry-pick, you will be sure there is no duplicated commits in your history
But I don't mean git rebase and git cherry-pick are bad commands, in fact, these commands are great!, the only thing you need is how to use them

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the Github for Windows settings:

[image]